# How i can add a new shape to Excalidraw project

Tags: reactjs, typescript, react-tsx

I have clone the repository of Excalidraw project, i want to add a new shape to toolbar, so anyone one can help me with that like, what and files i need to change, or what should be the approach or what is the code of shapes in excalidraw

Repo Link : https://github.com/excalidraw/excalidraw

I tried to follow the code flow of already existing shapes like how they have added for example Rectangle, but didn't get the expected output.

Answer (score 0):

Dont make a code change to get a new shape.
Create your desired shape, group it, and add it to library and use it